# Access Service in another cluster

Tags: istio, servicemesh

I deployed the istio mutlicluster using this URL https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary_multi-network/ , now i need to access the cluster two service from cluster one and cluster one from cluster two

Kubernetes Version: 1.19
Istio version: 1.6.8

Comment: What did you tried? Do you have any errors? (which?) Did you see [this doc](https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/setup/install/multicluster/verify/#verifying-cross-cluster-traffic)?

Comment: I need to access service in cluster A from cluster B and Service from cluster B in cluster A, and i did the verification and everything done but it's working as load balancer in the verification steps

Comment: What exactly happens when you are trying to access from one cluster to the other? How are you testing it? Are you getting any errors?